# Where should I store a client_secret key in Django?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I have built an `Android` app with a `Django REST` backend, using `django-rest-social-auth` (Oauth2). Everything works fine but I am wondering where/how should I store the `client_secret` (of the OAuth Django app created in /admin) key, used for the first call to convert my `user_token` (or username/password if logged by credentials) to an `access_token` that will be used in all the next calls.

Indeed, I have read that it cannot be stored within my Android app as it can be decompiled. Thus, I store it on my server and retrieve the right `client_secret` according to the incoming `client_id`. But I do not know if it is the classical way to handle it.

Comment: i don't know any thing thing about rest-framework but i know when we want to set a secret key we set it as a environment variable in django : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing secrets for Django on servers is often done with environment variables, though there are several libraries out there that aim to tidy up the process, I like [Django environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) for example though that does a bit more than simply hide secrets.